# How to use substringWithRange() with a startIndex and a length in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I currently use substringWithRange() with an start index and a length:

```
let str = "Hello World"

let index = 0
let length = 3

str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: str.startIndex.advancedBy(index), end: str.startIndex.advancedBy(index + length))) // "Hel"
```

This works fine, but is there any way, to use a simpler more elegant syntax?

I could use NSRange, but I only want to use pure Swift code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no other way to do it in swift. But you can create your own extension if you really need it:

```
extension String {

    func substringWithRange(var aRange: Range<Index.Distance>) -> String {
        aRange.startIndex = max(aRange.startIndex, 0)
        aRange.endIndex = max(aRange.endIndex, aRange.startIndex)
        return substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(
            start: startIndex.advancedBy(aRange.startIndex),
            end: startIndex.advancedBy(aRange.endIndex)))
    }

}
```

Now you can do the following:

```
str.substringWithRange(index..<index+length)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String
{
    public func substringWithRange(range: Range<Index.Distance>) -> String
    {
        return substringWithRange(startIndex.advancedBy(range.startIndex)..<startIndex.advancedBy(range.endIndex))
    }
}

str.substringWithRange(index..<index + length)
```